# Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot

When I try to install Ubuntu on dualboot it shows you have to turn off intel rst but my pc did have the option to change sata or AHCI.

Comment: This is not easy to deal with on dual boot. If you switch to ahci, Windows won't boot. That's why many vendors removed this option.

Comment: i need help...how to boot then with ubantu

Comment: There is no easy way to install. It is more or less easy to boot from a LiveUSB using `mdadm` but you won't be able to boot after install.

Comment: Can you use boot-repair with live disk?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to do a fresh install of Windows without using RAID and after that install Ubuntu.

The disks should be reformatted.

Generally RST is not a problem for Ubuntu if you install it alone. But if you have Windows installed using some RAID configuration, installing Ubuntu on that RAID is really tricky. `grub` doesn't support this RAID yet.

It is possible to install Ubuntu on an RST RAID without using `grub` and with `mdadm`, but it is too complex for a newbie.

If you are not prepared to lose all your existing data, I recommend to forget about installing Ubuntu till the installer and boot loader support Intel RST officially.

Comment: i need talk with u...how to contact with u....my pc is windows home based...i'm confused...can we talk on whatsapp or any other media

Comment: I recommend to forget the idea to install Ubuntu with Windows on this comp, unless you are prepared to wipe all your disks and install Windows and Ubuntu from scratch. There is no reliable straight forward way to install Ubuntu now. You need lots of knowledge to try doing it.

Comment: how to install using raid...actually i want dual boot i dont wana my windows perdformance should go decrease

Comment: There is no easy way as I wrote before.

Comment: so guide me then step by step...i will do thar

Comment: I can't guide you step by step. And nobody can.

Comment: what to do now...so i will b unable  using linux

Comment: i only buy pc with ssd ,dont know this problem happens...i just wana use linux